# Is the Info Hash of torrent file only generared by the file?

Tags: bittorrent

Uploader usually post the info hash of torrent file on the webpage, is this the same to sha1, 2 ,256... hashsum which only direct to the original file?

Comment: How does this relate to Unix & Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of What exactly is the info_Hash in a torrent file – dswdsyd---------Just a combination of components, so it looks a kind of ms5...